# Current.Server.MapPath taking long time to retrive mapped path

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm using `Current.Server.MapPath(virtualPath);` method in my asp.net application to retrieve mapped path. my profiler showing that this operation taking considerable time to execute. it called `ProcessHostConfigUtils:GetSiteNameFromId` and that call taking considerable time to return.

```
-System.Web.HttpRequest:MapPath (method time = 0 ms, total time = 2964 ms)
-->System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment:MapPathActual (method time = 0 ms, total time = 2964 ms)
--->System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath:MapPathCaching (method time = 0 ms, total time = 2964 ms)
---->System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostConfigUtils:GetSiteNameFromId (method time = 2964 ms, total time = 2964 ms)
```

Site is hosted on load balanced environment. Any ideas how to improve this execution time.

Comment: The source code is here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Configuration/ProcessHostConfigUtils.cs,67e2cce3329f855f  It looks like the result is cached in a variable so it should only be slow the first time.

Comment: That shows all the time is in GetSiteNameFromId as you said. Have a look at the sources for it (via ILSpy or .NET Reflector or whatever or from MS if it's available on GitHub).

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this.  I'm having a similar issue.